# Is 2s a subshell or an orbital?

Tags: electronic-configuration

My textbook says

> They will then fill the $2s$ subshell, and then the $2p$ subshell...

Yet half of ChemSE refers to $s,p,d,f$ as "subshells" and the other half seems to refer to $1s, 2p...$ for example, as "subshells" as well, even in two answers to the same question.

So is, for example, $s$ a subshell, or $2s$ a subshell?

Comment: Am I Ivan _or_ Ivan Neretin?

Comment: @IvanNeretin You are ИСН:)

Comment: Terms a shell and a subshell are rather obsolete.2 means the orbital with quantum number n=2, p means the orbital with quantum number l=0. By the particular subshell were considered orbitals with the particular quantum numbers n and l.

Comment: @andselisk You knew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terms a shell and a subshell are rather obsolete.
2 in 2p means the orbital has the quantum number n=2, p in 2p means the orbital has the quantum number $\ell$=0.

By the particular subshell were considered orbitals with the particular quantum numbers n and l.

So s, p, d, f are particular groups of "subshells", each sharing the common value of the quantum number $\ell$=0,1,2,3,  while 1s, 2p,.. are the particular "subshells".